# WordPress Social Login Endpoint. 406. The session identifier is missing. For more information refer to WSL Troubleshooting

Tags: wordpress, plugins

WordPress Social Login- I have used this plugin for social login. After login by gmail and Facebook it is showing this error:

[image: WordPress Social Login Endpoint. 406. The session identifier is missing. For more information refer to WSL Troubleshooting]

I have done all settings, of Application ID and Application Secret. Same settings and plugin working on local but not on server.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue and did a lot of research and testing.

Here the solution for it.

Place the below code in your function.php file.

Don't forgot to update your domain name.

```
  function wsl_whitelist_endpoint()
  {
    setcookie( LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, md5(rand()), time()+15,'http://yourdomainnamegoeshere/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-social-login/hybridauth' );
  }
  add_filter( 'wsl_process_login_start', 'wsl_whitelist_endpoint' );
```